# Line pattern in a diamond in C

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C, I'm facing a problem in order to implement a diamond, I'm following guided exercises from a book but I got stuck, I have to implement the pattern:

[image]

According to the exercise, they suggest me to implement the pattern using the operator %
[image]

I coded the structure but when I want to implement the pattern @.o.@ I just destroy everything

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){
  int n, space;
  printf("Number of sides: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  space = n - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       
        for (int j = 0;j < space; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }

        // patern @.o should be in this loop
        for (int j = 0;j <= i*2; j++){
            printf("@");
        }

        printf("\n");
        space--;
  }
  space = 0;
  for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--){
        
        for (int j = 0; j < space; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        // patern @.o should be in this loop
        for (int j = 0;j < (i*2)-1;j++){
            printf("@");
        }

        printf("\n");
        space++;
    }

}
```

I really appreciate it if somebody could give me a hint or help with this, I got stuck here for the last 2 weeks.
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of printing `@`, use `j % 4` as index into the string `"@.o."`. BTW where is your code that _"just destroys everything"_? If you show us that, maybe we can tell you what's wrong

Comment: What is the "number of sides" stored in `n`? Just a hint, but naming things consistently and meaningfully is important for understanding. Avoid single-letter identifiers except for loop index variables!

Comment: your question got answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need

```
#include<stdio.h>



int main(){
  int n, space,i,j;
  char pattern[]={'@','.','o','.'};
  int position;
  printf("Number of sides: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  space = n - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){

        position=0;
        for (j = 0;j < space; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }

        // patern @.o should be in this loop
        for (j = 0;j <= i; j++,position++)
            printf("%c",pattern[position%sizeof(pattern)]);

        position-=2;
        for(;j<=2*i;j++,position--)
            printf("%c",pattern[position%sizeof(pattern)]);

        printf("\n");
        space--;
  }
}
```

The output for some cases:

```
./test
Number of sides: 10
         @
        @.@
       @.o.@
      @.o.o.@
     @.o.@.o.@
    @.o.@.@.o.@
   @.o.@.o.@.o.@
  @.o.@.o.o.@.o.@
 @.o.@.o.@.o.@.o.@
@.o.@.o.@.@.o.@.o.@

./test
Number of sides: 5
    @
   @.@
  @.o.@
 @.o.o.@
@.o.@.o.@

./test
Number of sides: 2
 @
@.@
```

For a diamond:

```
#include<stdio.h>



int main(){
  int n, space,i,j;
  char pattern[]={'@','.','o','.'};
  int position;
  printf("Number of sides: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  space = n - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){

        position=0;
        for (j = 0;j < space; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (j = 0;j <= i; j++,position++)
            printf("%c",pattern[position%sizeof(pattern)]);

        position-=2;
        for(;j<=2*i;j++,position--)
            printf("%c",pattern[position%sizeof(pattern)]);

        printf("\n");
        space--;
  }

space = 0;
  for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){

        for (int j = 0; j < space; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        position=0;

        for (j = 0;j <= i; j++,position++)
            printf("%c",pattern[position%sizeof(pattern)]);

        position-=2;
        for(;j<=2*i;j++,position--)
            printf("%c",pattern[position%sizeof(pattern)]);

        printf("\n");
        space++;
    }
}
```

And the output

```
 ./test
Number of sides: 10
         @
        @.@
       @.o.@
      @.o.o.@
     @.o.@.o.@
    @.o.@.@.o.@
   @.o.@.o.@.o.@
  @.o.@.o.o.@.o.@
 @.o.@.o.@.o.@.o.@
@.o.@.o.@.@.o.@.o.@
@.o.@.o.@.@.o.@.o.@
 @.o.@.o.@.o.@.o.@
  @.o.@.o.o.@.o.@
   @.o.@.o.@.o.@
    @.o.@.@.o.@
     @.o.@.o.@
      @.o.o.@
       @.o.@
        @.@
         @
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to just change printf("@") to printf("%c",pattern[j%4])

Here is a code:

```
int main(){
  int n, space;
  char pattern[4] = {'@','.','o','.'};
  printf("Number of sides: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  space = n - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        for (int j = 0;j < space; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }

        // patern @.o should be in this loop
        for (int j = 0;j <= i*2; j++){
            printf("%c",pattern[j%4]);
        }

        printf("\n");
        space--;
  }

  space = 0;
  for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--){

        for (int j = 0; j < space; j++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        // patern @.o should be in this loop
        for (int j = 0;j < (i*2)-1;j++){
            printf("%c",pattern[j%4]);
        }

        printf("\n");
        space++;
    }
}
```

The reason why you "destroy everything" is probably because you tried to do it with printf(pattern[j%4]). printf as first parameter wants string (address in memory when string is stored) when you pass pattern[j%4], it thinks that for example '@' (in ASCII 64) is adress in memory, and want to read from it, but it is not valid memory adress so operating system kill your program and it "get's destroyed"

Comment: That code doesnt work, if you check it with 10 sides the sides of the diamond are wrong.

Comment: Hi, you are right, thanks. But your's is working so i think question is answered :)

Comment: Thanks to everybody that took the time to answer my question, I really appreciate this community. Thank you @hamboy75 and  Łukasz Strugała in particular for your time. Finally, I couldn't use any of your ideas, because I'm using a particular version of C called C+- so the arrays work different the are called vectors and Is very messy, I tried to implement the same with a if else system but is not working at all. I'm going to fight it and If I surrender I'lll post gain here. Thanks again and good luck with your projects.